# Can I pass operators into an NSPredicate via the format string?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, predicate

I'm trying to create the following predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != %@ AND date %@ %@", varName, operator, varDate]
```

Where `varName` and `varDate` are NSString and NSDate objects respectively. The `operator` variable is declared like so:

```
NSString *operator = (direction == kPageDirectionForward) ? @">" : @"<";
```

Basically I want to save a couple lines when creating the predicate. I know I can create different predicates based on the value of `direction`, but this use case has me thinking.

Right now this current method crashes, so I don't think its possible. I'm wondering if anyone else has had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it because the format string is different to the supplied parameters, as in the supplied parameters will be quoted when the format string is processed to generate a valid and parseable predicate string.

Comment: have to wait 6 minutes to accept this answer. Sorry if I forget, thanks for the response that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a combination of `NSComparisonPredicate` and `NSCompoundPredicate`:

```
// First part: name != <varName>
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != %@", varName];

// Second part: date <op> <varDate>
NSExpression *lexp = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date"];
NSExpression *rexp = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:varDate];
NSPredicateOperatorType op = (direction == kPageDirectionForward) ? NSGreaterThanPredicateOperatorType : NSLessThanOrEqualToPredicateOperatorType;
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:lexp
                                                     rightExpression:rexp
                                                            modifier:0
                                                                type:op
                                                             options:0];
// predicate = <p1> AND <p2>
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2]];
```

Comment: OK, this would not "save a couple lines" as you said, but how to create a predicate dynamically at runtime might be interesting anyway.

Comment: trying to save lines of code, so I probably won't use this, but definitely glad I know its possible. This looks like the correct answer if you want to create predicates dynamically

Answer (score 2):

I realize this isn't fundamentally different than op's statement about using different predicate strings, but you can build the predicate string dynamically:

```
NSString *operator = (direction == kPageDirectionForward) ? @">" : @"<";

NSMutableString * predicateString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"name != %@ AND date "];
[predicateString appendString: operator];
[predicateString appendString: @" %@"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString, varName, varDate];
// should return valid predicate: @"name != %@ AND date < %@"
```

And as a slightly more bizarre example, this should work as long as you're querying against nsobjects:

```
NSString * predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"name != %@ AND date %@ %@", @"%@", operator, @"%@"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString, varName, varDate];
```

Answer (score 2):

Really there's a more efficient way to do this:

```
NSString *dateOperator = (direction == kPageDirectionForward) ? @">" : @"<";
NSString *stringPredicate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%K != %%@ AND %%K %@ %%@", dateOperator];

NSPredicate *yourPredicate=[NSPredicate stringPredicate argumentArray:@[@"name",varName,@"date",varDate]];
```

Comment: This is really the most explicit and concise answer.